# Deduce the derivative from known the derivative of it composite with other.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2} $ and $ g: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ defined by

$$f(t) = (t,t^2)$$ 
and $$g(x,y)=xy+y^2$$

Fist find $f'(t)$ and $(g \circ f)'(t)$, then deduce what is the derivative of $g$.

I did the fist part, and found

$$f'(t) = (1,2t)$$
and 
$$(g \circ f)'(t) = 3t^2+4t^3$$

But I don't know how to deduce what is the derivative of $g$.

Comment: $g(f'(t)) = 2t^{2} + 4t^{3}$ ..$f'(t) =  (x,y)$

Comment: @K.Dutta Isn't $g(f'(t))=2t+4t^2$? and why $f'(t)=(x,y)$?